# Portable class library for Google Drive Api namespace referencing

Tags: google-api, windows-phone, portable-class-library

I am developing a Windows Phone application which needs to read google docs spreadsheets and came to a problem on the first stemp. According to the accepted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728441/google-apis-client-library-for-net-on-windows-phone-7-project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api) topics I have created something like this in the Portable class library

```
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

public void Read()
{
    SpreadsheetsService myService = new SpreadsheetsService("service");
    myService.setUserCredentials("username@provider.com", "password");

    SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = myService.Query(query);

    foreach (SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries)
    {

    }
}
```

When trying to build it I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is a Windows Phone 7.1 app and the PCL is setup to .Net 4+, Silverlight 4+ windows phone 7.5+

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCL projects cannot use platform specific-libraries, they can only use other PCL libraries which also must support compatible platforms. While referencing may work as in your case but you can't actually use them.

Read [this](http://kishore1021.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/what-is-portable-class-library-project-in-visual-studio-2012-net-4-5/) for more info.

However, since the Google Data API is an open source project you could make a PCL and take the functionality you need from their API and add it to your PCL and use that instead.