# Google.Apis.Authentication 1.5.0-beta runtime error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, google-calendar-api

while trying to create a windows phone app.
i want to use google calendar, and i just cant find out the way to install the framework.
am following the google example right in this link:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup

i used the package manager console with the follow command

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Pre
```

and runs all fine.
when i use this:

```
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
```

i get a runtime error. on 0Auth2 that sais that the name space doesnt exit.
i try to use again the package manager console with the follow code:

```
    PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Authentication -Pre
```

and i get this message:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Google.Apis.Authentication 1.5.0-beta'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Authentication -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, that package does not target WP7.1.

Comment: well i also tryied with windows phone 8 as well. does that means that i cant use this api to develop a windows app ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google APIs Client Library for .NET on Windows Phone 7 Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728441/google-apis-client-library-for-net-on-windows-phone-7-project)